# http://localhost:1000/api/todos 404 Not Found using ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

Installed ServiceStack through nuget:
Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.Mvc on a new MVC4 app.

Reading the "ReadMe.txt" it says:
to comment out WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration) in the Global.asax file so it doesn't interfere with ServiceStack.

and also add this to it in order for it to work:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon
```

Here is my Global.asax:

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

           // WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

            RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
            RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

            BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
            BootstrapMvcSample.ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.IsLocal)
                ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Start();
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Stop();
        }
    }
```

This is how nuget configured the web.config:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Running the project, it auto starts the default.htm page which has a BackBone UI bound to /api/ URI which returns 404, am I missing something?

Comment: Have you removed the webapi stuff that comes with mvc4 projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order the routes are registered is important. I think you need to either add the lines

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

or add the lines to the RouteConfig.cs files before the `routes.MapRoute()` line

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```